# Swift value changes to static when entering SKScene

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, combine

I have a SwiftUI View holding a SpriteView. This SpriteView receives a Double value successful from a combine variable sitting in a conductor class:

```
var passThrough = PassthroughSubject<Double, Never>()
```

This is the SwiftUI View which receives the PassthroughSubject correct.

```
struct SpriteKitView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
    var scene = GameScene()
    
    init(sharedViewModel:SharedViewModel){
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        scene.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        self.sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        SpriteView(scene: scene, options: [.allowsTransparency])
            .onReceive(sharedViewModel.conductor.passThrough){ ( value ) in
                
                print("Received Double: \(value)")
                
                scene.scaleVar = CGFloat(value)
            }
    }
}
```

The GameScene is just a circle drawn as a SKShapeNode. Within the Update you can see the passThrough enter like so:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
        
    var scaleVar: Double = 0
    var myObject: SKShapeNode!
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        node.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        node.fillColor = SKColor.orange
        myObject = node
        addChild(myObject)
    }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        
        print("Update Double: \(scaleVar)")
        
        myObject.setScale(CGFloat(scaleVar))
        
        print("Update CGFloat: \(CGFloat(scaleVar))")
                
    }
}
```

Going from SwiftUI to the SpriteKit the value gets converted to a random Number. See this console output of the prints within the code:

Received Double: 0.9631603454475357 <- correct value

Update Double: 0.03565312499999999 <- random static??

Update CGFloat: 0.03565312499999999 <- random static??

Update Double: 0.03565312499999999 <- random static??

Update CGFloat: 0.03565312499999999 <- random static??

Why is the update not receiving the send Double. The same thing happens when I translate to CGFloat before sending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and put it into a new iOS app project replacing the default "ContentView" with your SpriteKitView and and the following implementation of a SharedViewModel.  I could not reproduce the results you report.  The double value is published as expected in every case.  Is there perhaps another explanation in your code?

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit
import Combine


class SharedViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var passThrough = PassthroughSubject<Double, Never>()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.sendDoubles()
    }

    private func sendDoubles() {
        Task {
            var angle = 0.0
            while(true) {
                guard !Task.isCancelled else { break }
                angle = fmod(angle + 0.1, 2 * Double.pi)
                passThrough.send(sin(angle))
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(1.0e8))
            }
        }
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var scaleVar: Double = 0
    var myObject: SKShapeNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        node.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        node.fillColor = SKColor.orange
        myObject = node
        addChild(myObject)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        print("Update Double: \(scaleVar)")

        myObject.setScale(CGFloat(scaleVar))

        print("Update CGFloat: \(CGFloat(scaleVar))")

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
    var scene = GameScene()

    init(sharedViewModel:SharedViewModel){
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        scene.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        self.sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene, options: [.allowsTransparency])
            .onReceive(sharedViewModel.passThrough.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)){ ( value ) in

                print("Received Double: \(value)")

                scene.scaleVar = CGFloat(value)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I've added an extra abstraction layer which broke things. Looks like I'll need to monitor closer while refactoring.